# Modifying letters in a file

Tags: python, file

I'm new to programming so I'm pretty lost. I'm currently learning Python and I need to open a text file and change every letter to the next one in the alphabet (e.g a -> b, b -> c, etc.). How would I go about writing a code like this?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a neat problem to work on for a beginner.

Things you may want to look at:

The `open()` function, which allows you to open files and read/write to them. For example

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

```
with open('test.out', 'r+') as fi:
    all_lines = fi.readlines()  # Read all lines from the file
    fi.write('this string will be written to the file')
# The file is closed at this point in the code; `with()` is a context manager, look that up
```

The `os.replace()` function, which lets you overwrite one file with another. You might try reading the input file, writing to a new output file, then overwriting the input file with the new output file; this will let you do that.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace

Replacing a character with the next increment of a character is an interesting twist, as it's not something that a lot of python programmers have to deal with. Here's one way to increment a character:

```
x = 'c'
print(chr(ord(x) + 1))  # will print 'd'
```

Without just giving away the answer, this should give you the pieces that you need to get started, feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work very well. The code can be shortened I think but Im still not sure how. Not an expert with `with open` statements.

```
with open("(your text file path)", "r") as f:
    data = f.readline()
    
new_data = ""
for x in range(len(data)):
    i = ord(data[x][0])
    i += 1
    x = chr(i)

    new_data += x
    print(new_data)

with open("(your text file path)", "w") as f:
    f.write(new_data)
```

You must change your letters to numbers so that you can increment them by one, and then change them back to letters. This should work.